# Giving newuser root permissions after disabling the root

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, root

As stupid as I am a have disabled the root account before I gave my new user account permissions.. any Idea how I can enable the root user again or give my new user the root permission. Every time I try to acces sudo I get a acces denied message, If I try to log in to the root account it says it has been disabled.

Answer (score 1):

The exact procedure is different depending on what distribution of Linux you are using but you want to either single user boot the system or use grub to enter recovery mode.  For Debian based systems you usually can edit the kernel parameters in the grub menu and include `rw init=/bin/bash`, and on CentOS versions before 7 you can add the word single (or just the letter s) to the end of that same line.

Helpful links for forgotten password reset procedures : [Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-help/user-forgottenpassword.html) , [CentOS 7](http://www.unixmen.com/reset-root-password-centos-7/)

Comment: Reset forgotten password on RHEL/CentOS 5,6 - https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/4022-reset-root-password-on-centos-5-6